# enum class XX : uint8_t vs enum XX : uint8_t: compilation err with bitwise operator and

Tags: c++, enums

I have the following code:

```
enum class MouseState : uint8_t
{
    kLeft = 0x01,
    kRight = 0x02,
    kMiddle = 0x04,
};

uint8_t mouseState { 0 };

if ((mouseState & MouseState::kLeft) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "okay\n";
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') and 'MouseState')
                        if ((mouseState & MouseState::kLeft) != 0) {
                             ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But if I use (where the keyword **class** was removed):

```
enum MouseState : uint8_t
{
   ...
};
```

it compiles fine. Could you explain why please? (using c++20 with clang).

Comment: An `enum class` is a *scoped* enumeration and cannot be implicitly converted to its underlying type. Therefore it doesn't implicitly support any kind of arithmetic or bitwise operations (you could overload operators to support it)

Comment: @UnholySheep thank you. But why is there a difference (of behavior) between `enum class xx` and `enum xx` in this context?

Comment: Because a regular `enum` is an *unscoped* enumeration and supports implicit conversion to the underlying type (most likely for legacy code support), see more details on cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: @UnholySheep ah yes sorry I didn't really read your first answer properly. I got it many thx. Happy to accept this as an answer. If you make your comment as one. Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Scoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> There are *no implicit conversions* from the values of a scoped
> enumerator *to integral types*, although
> [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)
> may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

Thus and because of increased type safety, I'd stick with `enum class` and `static_cast`, unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: I would eventually stay with enum XX because I need these bitwise ops, and overloading them as suggested by @UnholySheep is overkilled imho (didn't remove anything to the fact that I appreciate his/her suggestion).

Comment: One doesn't exclude the other - you could still `static_cast<uint8_t>(MouseState::kLeft)` and use bitwise ops.

Comment: yes totally (@SebastianWilke), thx for pointing this out, though this wouldn't be very usable code if people other than me needed to use it). I mean not very API friendly.

Comment: @user18490 Theoretically, you could also overload bitwise operators for your enum, for example, provide a `MouseState operator &(const MouseState& left, const MouseState& right);`, but yeah… you'll need to overload a lot of those, and, in many cases you'll still have to use a `static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<MouseState>>(…);` at least when interpreting the result of the operation. Thus, not very practical.

Comment: @user18490 Another remark is that you could use the regular (unscoped) `enum` (instead of `enum class`), but put it into a small namespace (like `namespace MouseStates { enum MouseState : std::uint8_t { … }; }`). That way you'll still preserve the _scoped_  advantage of `enum class` (avoiding global namespace pullution), while also preserving the _implicit conversion_ advantage of regular `enum`s.